# How to perform Interpretability analysis toward a simple reinforcement learning network

Tags: reinforcement-learning

We are currently using a RL network with the following simple structure to train a model which helps to solve a transformation task:

Environment (a binary file) + reward ---> LSTM (embedding)  --> FC layer --> FC layer --> FC layer --> decision (to select and apply a kind of transformation toward the environment from a pool of transformations)

The model will receive a simple reward and also take the input to make the decision. And we have a condition to stop each episode.

So the current workflow, although it is simple, it seems to have learned something and with multiple episode of training, we can observe the accumulated reward for each episode increases. So right now, what we are thinking is to `interpret` the model, well, a fancy term.

So basically we are thinking to let the model tell us from which component of the Environment (input file), the model somewhat makes the decision to select a transformation to apply. And I have learned a bunch of interpretability articles, which basically use an activation map (e.g., [link](https://jacobgil.github.io/deeplearning/class-activation-maps?nsukey=AWNe1ED4Qk%2FmkOWgGIXn0dabS%2Bz4VNo%2BkEnUhfw0sUs2ViTBewAdmlgUoGfbTOlXUFnPrwHzzYjPMf9r2xJytPnXx%2BScM6tYqPH52ogxtLywL6auw2DlxLQ1rJo1QeVXu1Nujvpirc9EEhd%2F2YFQONv9SUIBgbYhgDSf2ZaQekWUa%2Bc3jnMDT9i1qVsC4A%2BS6nxfRgEH%2BGeAvYXUwNCoxw%3D%3D)) to highlight certain components from the input.

However, the problem is that, we don't have any sort of CNN layer in our simple RL model. In that sense, the aforementioned method cannot apply, right? I also learned a number of techniques from this [book](https://christophm.github.io/interpretable-ml-book/simple.html), but still, I don't see any specific techniques applicable for RL models.

So here is my question, in terms of our simple RL model, how can we do certain "interpretability" analysis and therefore have a better idea on which part of the "Environment" leads to each step of decision? Thank you very much.